# can i use heroku post build script on azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, web-deployment

hi i have a nodejs and reactjs application in my local , developed the application from a boiler plate code , in boiler plate code package.json i have these following scripts

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
}
```

as of i know it can be deployed on heroku with these scripts , can i use same scripts to deploy on azure , do i need to change anything here .

```
   // Serve static assets if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

and this is what i have in my `server.js` as a starting point. i don't have any config folder to diff environments.for an example

```
// i don't have this folder structure and am not using webpack
-- config
     |-- dev.json
     |-- prod.json
```

can some one suggest , what is the best way to deploy it , or can i use same post-build script by changing it key like `azure-postbuild`

edited : i think i should use `postinstall` instead of `heroku-postbuild`